# Windows 7 PPTP VPN problem

Tags: windows, networking, mac-osx, pptp, osx-snow-leopard

I'm currently using an win 7 as an network server at my home.

I've created some shared folders wich can be accessed easily from any pc on my network (win and mac computers)

recently I decided to turn on the win 7 pptp to access remotely to my server from anywhere. the problem is with that on, on my router my server ip change, acording to my ipconfig on the cmd my router gets the ip from a "PPP adapter RAS (dial in)".

when that happens I cannot access to the shared files over the lan on my mac, but i can connect to the vpn but again can't access to my files. (i've tried connecting to the vpn from another network and it worked, even the file share)

anyone can help me?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean, your IP of the router is changing (your Internet address) or your workstation running the VPN server is having it's internal IP change?

Answer (score 0):

If your internal IP is changing on the workstation using the VPN server, configure it with a static IP addresss outside of your DHCP server's handled addresses. Then it won't change over time.

Comment: which one? on the pptp connection or the regular one? I've already put the pptp range from 192.168.2.100 to 120 and my default network ip's are 192.168.1.x

Comment: Which IP keeps changing so you can't connect? The router, or your workstation?